# Did Ubuntu just brick my computer?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I was trying to create a dual boot, and I installed Ubuntu 14.04 using a DVD that I created with an .iso file. I downloaded the .iso from the [Ubuntu Downloads Page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). After it asked me to remove the DVD and reboot, it booted to a black screen. It has not booted to anything except said screen since. It will not get to POST, there is no beep, and the BIOS menu doesn't appear. I have disconnected everything from the computer's USB ports except the USB keyboard, and the mouse. I have disconnected the SSD and DVD to get into BIOS, but to no avail. It just boots to the black screen. I would love to try the grub fix, but I can't get the machine to boot to anything. How should I proceed in attempting to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I don't mean to sound like your Mother here, but did you follow a set of instructions on how to dual-boot? Installing Ubuntu besides a pre-existing installation can be challenging, especially if it is your first time using the OS! As for your question, we'll need a little more information on ***exactly*** what happens when you boot up. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/738365/edit) your question, and try to give us some more understanding of what your issue is. All of this is so that we can better understand your problem, and further help you :)

Comment: @DavidCole-GrammarPolice It seems pretty clear to me; OP can't even reach POST.

Comment: OP: Try unplugging the computer from power completely and holding down the power button for 10 or more seconds before plugging it back in. If you have a laptop, remove the battery as well.

Comment: OP here.  I followed the instructions on the site for dual boot. While I am not new to Linux, it has been 8 years since I last installed.  My question/problem is after installing from a dvd created from the official 14.04 download iso, I cannot reach BIOS. The machine does not go into POST either.  The screen is black.  I have tried unplugging everything (SSD, dvd, all usb cables) but power and video hdmi, even moved power directly to the wall, tried everything I can think of.

Comment: I had an issue similar to this happen to me on my Dell desktop after installing Ubuntu. Turned out to be a error message the BIOS was displaying on the screen because of secure boot, but it only appeared after I put in the graphics card that came with it OEM. It was just sitting at black screen with my APOS graphics card installed.

Comment: Does you system boot from DVD?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but put the dvd back in the tray and start it up,see if BIOS tries to boot from the DVD.

Comment: Same issue.  Put disk back in and the screen was just black.

Comment: Oh, that's a bummer. I know for my machine,  I can download a detailed manual in PDF. See if you can find one. There should be a few function keys that will give you options when starting up, F12, F5, etc. You could just randomly try tapping on them when it starts up.